# Modulo negativo y decimal - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function mod(n, m) {
  return ((n % m) + m) % m;
}

console.log("Segundo Operador de modulo negativo:")
console.log(mod(3, -.2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
console.log(mod(-3, -.2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
console.log(mod(.3, -.2)) // BIEN
console.log(mod(-.3, -.2)) // BIEN
console.log(mod(3.6, -.2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
console.log(mod(-3.6, -.2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0

console.log("")
console.log("")

console.log("Segundo Operador de modulo positivo:")
console.log(mod(3, .2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
console.log(mod(-3, .2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
console.log(mod(.3, .2)) // BIEN
console.log(mod(-.3, .2)) // BIEN
console.log(mod(3.6, .2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
console.log(mod(-3.6, .2)) // ¿? RPTA: 0
```

Hola tengo la siguiente duda, ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de operar modulo con valores negativos y decimales? En el ejemplo 1 muestro varios numeros enteros positivos, decimales y negativos seguidos de un numero decimal negativo: -.2 y en el segundo un numero decimal positivo: .2.

Al ejecutar sus operaciones, su resultado es inesperado, nose si esto sea un bug de Javascript o un error de jerarquia de las operaciones que estoy tratando de realizar. Agradezco que me pudieran decir por que sucede esto.

Comment: `... su resultado es inesperado ...`. Pues dependerá de lo que esperes: ¿ Que resultados esperabas conseguir ?

Comment: @Juanjo el resultado esperado es 0, como se sabe, el modulo toma como resultado el residuo de una division, en este caso: 3 % -0.2 . Ambos numeros deben ser multiplicados por 10, para luego operar, 30 % -2 = 0. Entonces una buena solucion podria ser convertir el decimal a entero.

Comment: Como tu dices js tiene ciertos problemas para operar decimales, por lo que es recomendable trabajar con enteros.

Comment: El [módulo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operación_módulo) como operación matemática, se define sobre el conjunto de los números naturales (enteros positivos). ¿Porqué razón crees que puedes aplicarlo a negativos y/o racionales? Saludos